# Bind two arrays into one group of checkboxes - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have a JSON object that contains an array of items (which have name and id) and also an array of selected items (which would have only ids of the items from previous array that has been selected).

What I want to render on HTML page is a group of checkboxes (i.e. one checkbox per available item) that will be also binded to the second array of selected items. I know how to do it in JQuery, but I wonder if there is a clean "angularJS-way" of handling this and binding it somehow to the model.

So when the page is rendered, I want certain checkboxes to be selected (as per the second array) and also whenever I select/deselect an item, it should either appear/disappear from that array.

Hope I explained properly - I cannot change the structure of JSON source object as it's retrieved from the server and I have no control over it.

JSFiddle below - its obviously not working - I dont know what should I bind ng-model to for each check box.

http://jsfiddle.net/ej7mhv71/

```
    <span ng-repeat="item in object.stock">
      <label class="checkbox" for="{{item.id}}">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="object.selected[item.id]" id="{{item.id}}" />
          {{item.name}}<br/>
      </label>
    </span>



   $scope.object = {"stock":[ { "name": "Item1", "id": "1" } , 
                              {"name": "Item2", "id": "2" }, 
                              {"name": "Item3", "id": 3}], "
                    selected":{"ids":[1,2]}}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What would you like `$scope.object` to look like if I unchecked `Item2`?

Comment: @RGraham stock array object remains the same, but selected array changes to {"ids":[1]}

Comment: its not hard. but it requires other way. i'd rather say a dirty way as your json doesn't look so nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not saying its a best way to do it but I solved your problem without changing the JSON. I used the `ng-init="item.IsSelected = (object.selected.ids.indexOf(item.id*1) != -1)"` to make your item selected initially. Secondly I bind the fuction `ng-click="removeSelectedItem(item.id,item.IsSelected)"` to **Remove or Add** item from your Selected Item Array.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <span ng-repeat="item in object.stock">
      <label class="checkbox" for="{{item.id}}">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.IsSelected" ng-init="item.IsSelected = (object.selected.ids.indexOf(item.id*1) != -1)"  id="{{item.id}}" ng-click="removeSelectedItem(item.id,item.IsSelected)" />
          {{item.name}}<br/>
      </label>
    </span>
    <pre ng-bind="object | json"></pre>    
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
function Ctrl($scope) {

    $scope.object = {"stock":[ { "name": "Item1", "id": "1" } , {"name": "Item2", "id": "2" }, {"name": "Item3", "id": 3}], "selected":{"ids":[1,2]}}

    $scope.removeSelectedItem = function(itemId,isChecked){
        var selectedIndex =            $scope.object.selected.ids.indexOf(parseInt(itemId));

        var selectedItems =  $scope.object.selected.ids;
        if(isChecked){
            selectedItems.splice(selectedIndex,1);
        }
        else{
            if( selectedIndex == -1){
                selectedItems.push(parseInt(itemId))
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ej7mhv71/1/

Comment: It's a good solution, but I would suggest including the main parts of it in the answer. Imagine that the jsfiddle link is dead - will your answer make sense?

Comment: Functionally it works fine, but it does modify the JSON though - it adds isSelected to each stock item. So then when I send the JSON back to the server, I'm getting bad request (400).

Comment: The last thing you can do is to just remove the IsSelected property form your Stock Array before sending JSON to server.



`angular.forEach($scope.object.stock, function(item){
delete item.IsSelected;
});`